# SQL INSERT to table is not working

Tags: mysql, sql

So, I am trying to insert data via phpMyAdmin to a table named "tPerson". The SQL code is as follows:

```
INSERT INTO tPerson ( Salutation, FirstName, LastName, CompanyID )
VALUES ( Mr, Morris, Sparrow, 4, ), ( Mrs, Mary, Haslett, 2, ), ( Ms, Gill, Hennesey, 1, );
```

What is wrong with my code that is causing an error?

Comment: You're missing quotes around the values. The syntax is incorrect altogether. Take a look here: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/sql/sql-insert-query.htm

Comment: What is the `Mr, Morris, Sparrow`?

Comment: The ( Mr, Morris, Sparrow, 4 ) is data that is being inserted

Answer (score 2, accepted):

String values must be enclosed in quotes, preferred single quotes, numeric values don't need to be quoted, but MySQL tolerates quotes (other SQL dialects don't). In every group you've got to remove the trailing comma.

```
INSERT INTO tPerson (Salutation, FirstName, LastName, CompanyID) VALUES 
( 'Mr', 'Morris', 'Sparrow', 4 ), 
( 'Mrs', 'Mary', 'Haslett', 2 ), 
( 'Ms', 'Gill', 'Hennesey', 1 );
```

Your table and column names don't use reserved words and contain no special character, so they need no quotes. If you quote them, you've got to use backticks.